# Why are edges added as nodes in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

Why is `0,1,2` added to nodes upon adding edges (last print statement in code below)?

```py
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0)])
print(G.nodes) # >> [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
edges = [(0, 1),(1,2)]
G.add_edges_from(edges)
print(G.nodes) # >> [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), 0, 1, 2] ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NetworkX, nodes are identified by any hashable object. So the `add_nodes_from` call adds three nodes, each a tuple:

- `(0, 0, 0)`
- `(1, 0, 0)`
- `(1, 1, 0)`

Maybe you understood this already.

`add_edges_from` takes an iterable of 2-tuples (or 3-tuples), where each tuple identifies two nodes. So `(0, 1)` adds an edge between nodes `0` and `1`. These are node identifiers, not indices! And since these nodes don't exist yet, they are automatically added. This is [documented](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html):

> If some edges connect nodes not yet in the graph, the nodes are added automatically. There are no errors when adding nodes or edges that already exist.

What you probably meant to do is use the nodes' identifiers directly:

```
edges = [((0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)), ((1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0))]
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```